# SocialSharing Cordova using Wordpress JSON

Tags: json, wordpress, cordova, plugins, onsen-ui

Hi I'm using Social Sharing plug-in for cordava [https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin] by EddyVerbruggen

I follow the instructions and use this code example

```
<button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share(null, null, 'https://0.s3.envato.com/files/112367606/logo.png', null)">
```

and code working properly but when i try to implement data from wp JSON the sharing link are working but no image attach on share data unlike on given example.

Here's my code

```
<button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share(null, null, '{{ item.attachment[0].url', null)">
```

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

Your code has error, inspect element from your browser and have a look on your url in button onclick funtion it should not has a url value. error is in function arguments
(null, null, **'{{ item.attachment[0].url'**, null)

Comment: So how can i pull data image url from my wp JSON? 

when I use {{item.attaachment[0].url'}} on my content it shows my image link.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a problem in the image which is coming from the JSON try to print log the path so that you can identify whether the image path comes or not. Try using a temporary variable to assign the image path comes from JSON data and then assign the temporary variable name. I using the same in my project it works with dynamic paths.